# A horizontal navigation bar in a div

Tags: html, css

I've been creating a webpage for my cse homework...and I want to have a navigation bar at early of the site...Instead, I got this [nav bar below the borderline where it supposed to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9B13.jpg)

here's the code `

```
<body style="background: linear-gradient(#c3c3e5, #f1f0ff);">
<style>

#title {
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:30px;
    background-color:#443266;
}

#Welcome {
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-decoration: bold;
}

#q {
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:25px;
    text-align:justify;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

li {
    float:right;
}

li a {
    display:inline-block;

    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

#audio {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

</style>

    <div id="title">
    <p>Star Travel</p>

    <audio controls autoplay loop id="audio">
        <source src="../assets/audio/13_Fairy Law.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <br>
    <br>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="user-rev.html">Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="trip-accom.html">Accomodation</a></li>
        <li><a href="site-trip.html">Trip</a></li>
        <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

`

please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: not so understand.. what is your current appearance and your expected appearance?

Comment: Where do you like to put the menu? Inside the `STAR TRAVEL` div?

Comment: What do you mean by early of the site? At the top, above the purple box which says Star Travel?

Comment: yeah, in the star travel box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what u trying to do

```css
body{
  background: linear-gradient(#c3c3e5, #f1f0ff);
  margin: 0;
}
#title {
    font-family:courier;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:30px;
    background-color:#443266;
}
p{
  font-size:40px;
}

#Welcome {
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: bold;
}

#q {
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:25px;
    text-align:justify;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

li {
    float:left;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}

#audio {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="user-rev.html">Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="trip-accom.html">Accomodation</a></li>
        <li><a href="site-trip.html">Trip</a></li>
        <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>Star Travel</p>

    <audio controls autoplay loop id="audio">
        <source src="../assets/audio/13_Fairy Law.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <br>
    <br>

    
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You helped me